# batch file use parameter and string to create path

Tags: variables, batch-file, path, concatenation

I know there's a ton of stuff out there on this but I just can't make it work. What I want to do is

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%D IN (*) Do (
  ECHO %%D

  if not exists %%D.mp4 (
   rem cd %%D
   rem "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -i "VIDEO_TS" -o "..\%%D.mp4" --preset="High Profile" --x264-preset slow
   echo not exists
  )
  rem cd ..\
)
```

I left the extra stuff in there so you could see that I actually need the /D rather than a /R.  basically I'm converting the VIDEO_TS folder that is in an other folder into an mp4 of the parents name and putting it in the root.

the problem is checking if the file already exists. I can't figure out how to create a path that "exists" will recognize out of the var %%D and the suffix .mp4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

R

Comment: You haven't described the actual problem you're having.  You just said it "doesn't work".  For now, all it's doing is echoing the directory name and outputting something if the target file doesn't exist.  What is the exact problem?  Do your directory names contain spaces?  That would break your code, as it's currently written.

Comment: I added a bit of clarification to the post.   the exist check doesn't recognize the path.  my files do have horrible spaces in them I'm afraid.  Hadn't thought about that. the error I get varies as I've tried a million things but is basically '"%D.mp4" was unexpected at this time.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors here

1. The keyword is `EXIST`, not `EXISTS`.
2. You need to enclose the variable in double-quotes, due to spaces in filenames.

Example:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%D IN (*) DO (
  ECHO %%D

  IF NOT EXIST "%%D.mp4" (
   ECHO not exists
  )
)
```

Further, if you uncomment those other lines, you'll have issues because the `cd ..` is not at the same branching level as the `cd "%%D"` (note I added double-quotes here).  You should move that into the `IF` block.

However, instead of changing directory, you could simply pass `"%%D\VIDEO_TS"` to Handbrake.

```
FOR /D %%D IN (*) DO (
  IF NOT EXIST "%%D.mp4" (
     echo Encoding %%D ...
     "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -i "%%D\VIDEO_TS" -o "%%D.mp4" --preset="High Profile" --x264-preset slow
  )
)
```

Or you could use `pushd` and `popd`:

```
FOR /D %%D IN (*) DO (
  pushd .    
  IF NOT EXIST "%%D.mp4" (
     cd "%%D"
     echo Encoding %%D ...
     "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -i "VIDEO_TS" -o "..\%%D.mp4" --preset="High Profile" --x264-preset slow
  )
  popd
)
```

Comment: what.  just because there's a massive syntax error it doesn't work? how lame.  :)

Comment: You want a world where a compiler or language parser decides what it *thinks* you wanted? ... *"Hmmm, did you mean EXIST or EXIT?"*